# Why is Between not finding the end date

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vaccines 
WHERE (initial_date BETWEEN '1/1/2018' AND '10/31/2018') 
  AND customer_id='110607' 
  AND item_description= 'FLUZONE .QUAD MDV';
```

I get no results and there are entries for that date range, however, results are display till month 9, from 10 -12 I get nothing.

Comment: my guess is that you are using MM/DD/YYYY format for your string dates, change that to MySQL's default YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: what about sharing some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *Why is BETWEEN not finding the end date?*

A: Likely because MySQL is doing *string* comparison; comparing *string* values  not *date* values.

If we are comparing *strings*, note that any string starting with `'9'` 
is going to be greater than a string starting with `'1'`.

```
'9........'  is greater than '1........'
```

likewise

```
'9/23/1999'  is greater than '10/31/2001'
```

Even if we include leading zeros, comparing as *strings*, we are still going to run into problems with comparing the year:

```
'09/23/2018'  is less than   '10/31/2001'
       ^^^^                         ^^^^
```

---

If we want to make use of MySQL ability to compare date and datetime values, then we can use MySQL native `DATE` and `DATETIME` types, and avoid doing string comparisons.

If `initial_date` column is defined as `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype, then specify *date* values in the query, e.g.

```
 WHERE initial_date >= '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL 0 DAY 
   AND initial_date  < '2018-11-01' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

(Note: MySQL date literals can be represented as `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.)

---

If `initial_date` columns is defined as string type (e.g. CHAR or VARCHAR), then we can convert the string values into a *date* value using the `STR_TO_DATE` function e.g.

```
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(initial_date,'mm/dd/yyyy') >= '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL 0 DAY 
   AND STR_TO_DATE(initial_date,'mm/dd/yyyy')  < '2018-11-01' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

(Note that the second argument is a format model; the string will be interpreted according to that model.)

---

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM vaccines 
WHERE (initial_date BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-10-31' AS DATE)) 
  AND customer_id='110607' 
  AND item_description= 'FLUZONE .QUAD MDV';
```